# Time complexity of finding an integer between $x$ and $2x$

Tags: algorithms, primes

Consider receiving as input $x\in\mathbb N$ and computing some (any) prime $p\in[x,2x]$.

> **What is the complexity of the above problem?**

---

A natural way to approach this problem is to generate random integers in $x,\ldots,2x$ and check for their primality using Miller-Rabin or a deterministic algorithm such as AKS.

However, this may be suboptimal. What is the best-known runtime for the problem?

Comment: Asked on [crypto.se]: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-can-i-generate-large-prime-numbers-for-rsa.

Answer (score 2):

You can speed up this algorithm somewhat by generating a random integer which is coprime to all small primes. This can be done efficiently using a sieve: pick an appropriately sized random interval inside $[x,2x]$, and cross off all integers in the interval which are multiples of small primes (you can do this efficiently by finding the first multiple of a given prime, and then iterating over the remaining multiplies). Now use your favorite algorithm to find a prime within the integers not ruled out. The size of the interval should be chosen so that it guarantees that there is a prime (so about $\log x$ or somewhat larger).

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct to assume that this does not result in an asymptotical improvement? Or can we set the sieve cleverly to achieve that?

Comment: Since you mentioned the AKS algorithm, I assumed you're not interested in efficient algorithms.

Comment: It probably does result in an asymptotic improvement, since the sieving part is very fast, and it drastically improves your success probability. To know for sure, you'll have to do the calculation.

Comment: I also mentioned MR, which is probably the fastest option :).

Comment: By the way, having $O(1)$ small primes in the sieve probably does not allow for asymptotic reduction, so the number of small primes should be a function of $x$, and it's interesting whether such improvement is possible.

Comment: Given that you indicate selecting a random interval, it sounds like this is basically how fast can one perform a _nextprime_ operation.  Is there any way to improve this -- e.g. is there any way to select a "denser" area?  Asympotically isn't nextprime, even with a sieve, $\log n \times P$ where $P$ is $\log^k n$ where k depends on the primality test used (3 for BPSW probable prime; 4-6 for a proof method)?  Expect $O(\log n)$ tests costing $O(\log^3 n)$ each followed by one final primality test if desired.

Comment: I would guess that sieving buys you a superconstant speed-up. Finding an a priori denser area sounds very difficult.